# Gazebo: SetPosition() function in the Joint class doesn't set the joint position and returns false sometimes

Tags: simulation, gazebo

I am trying to initialize the positions of my robot using Gazebo Plugins. `SetPosition()` function of the `Joint` class is supposed to set the joint angle (all my joints are revolute joints). However, the function doesn't do anything. The function returns `false` indicating the action is unsuccessful. I have attached a simplified version of my code. I don't understand why it returns `false` always. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>

#include <ignition/math/Vector3.hh>

#include <gazebo/common/common.hh>
#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>
#include <gazebo/physics/physics.hh>

namespace gazebo {
class RobotInitialization : public ModelPlugin {
 public:
  void Load(physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr) {
    this->model = _parent;

    auto joint = this->model->GetJoint("revolute-joint");
    joint->SetPosition(0, 1.0, true);
    std::cout << joint->Position(0) << std::endl;
  }

 private:
  physics::ModelPtr model;
};
GZ_REGISTER_MODEL_PLUGIN(CassieInitialization)
}  // namespace gazebo
```

**Edit:**
Thanks for the suggestion. I checked the joint limits and this helped for 6 out of 16 joints on my robot. I set velocities for all joints using `SetVelocity()` and that works for all the joints but `SetPosition()` doesn't. I also checked DOF of the joints using `joint.DOF()` and it returns 1 for all my joints.

**Edit:**
I am using bullet as the solver.

Answer (score 0):

It's returning `false` because it's failing to set the joint angle. I would try to troubleshoot this by stepping through the different reasons it could fail.

The first thing that I think of, especially when I see a `Get<something>()` that has a string input, is that the name changed, isn't spelled correctly, etc. I would check first if you're actually getting a valid joint from your `GetJoint()` command:

```
if(joint==nullptr)
{
    std::cout<<"Joint not found!"<<std::endl;
}
else
{
    <your code here>
}
```

The next thing I would check is whether your joint has any degrees of freedom to actually move - that it's not fully constrained:

```
if(joint.DOF()==0)
{
    std::cout<<"Joint has zero degrees of freedom!"<<std::endl;
}
else
{
    <your code here>
}
```

I can't see in the documentation what *units* the inputs to `SetPosition()` are, but `Position()` returns *radians* and I'm assuming that `SetPosition()` is also expecting *radians*. You're inputting `1.0` *radians*, which is about 60 degrees, so I don't know if there are some kinematic constraints that are preventing that rotation.

Please do these checks and *edit your question* to post the results.

## :EDIT:

It looks like there's an [open bug](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/1913/cant-set-joint-state-when-using-simbody) for setting joint states when using SimBody, but it looks like maybe using ODE as the solver instead works.

Also, there's [another post](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12093/how-correctly-move-joints-by-setposition/) that suggests using a joint controller and setting the joint position target instead of trying to set the joint position directly.

Comment: Will the method using PID controller be instantaneous? I want to start my simulator paused. Also, I was wondering if modifying the sdf `initial_position` help.

Comment: @NKV - I don't think the PID controller will be instantaneous, or it wouldn't be a controller. In your edit you said the joint limits... something... for 6 of 16 joints. You said SetVelocity() works but SetPosition() doesn't, so the edit I made above collects the results of me searching for that problem - that you can set velocity but not position. Ultimately I don't have your model so it's really hard to troubleshoot what's going on, but it sounds like some kind of a configuration issue, especially if not all joints are responding the same.